# GitHub issues in pushing to a newly created repo

Tags: git, github

I can't push any thing to GitHub from the moment I added a ssh to my account and I don't know what the issues is or how to deal or even avoid it ?
[image]

Comment: Please consider showing us what you did, what the result was, and what you expected to happen. Until then, there isn't much that can be done to help you, there aren't any details to work with here.

Comment: This is an example of a bad question. You must provide coded examples of your attempts, a detailed description of your issue, your current input, and a detailed description of your desired output. See [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

and then push your contents.

Comment: well, it didn't solve my problem